# Limits of continuous functions and the intermediate-value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, infinitesimals

Let $f : (0, ∞) → \mathbb{R}$ be a function for which $[f(x) · f(1/x)]<0$, for every $x>0$ where $x$ is not equal to $1$.
Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x'=1$, then $f(1) = 0$.

Notice that according to the given information, $f(x)>0$ and $f(1/x)<0$ (or the other way around).

I'm trying to figure out if the above statement is true or false, but I have mixed feelings and I'm not sure if it's false or if it's true and there is something that I'm missing.

According to the intermediate-value theorem, if it was given that $f$ is continuous for every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or even (just as an example) every $x$ in $(0,2)$, then no problem. But it's not given and this is all the information given to me, and I can't be sure if this means that it's false or not.
I also can't think of a solid way of disproving the statement and therefore I'm stuck.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Define $g(x) = f(x)f(\dfrac{1}{x}). g(1) = f^2(1) \geq 0$ because $f$ is real-valued. $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous at $x = 1$, so $g(x)$ can be shown to be continuous because of the rules for products and compositions of continuous functions. Now, suppose $g(1) > 0$. Can you use the definition of a limit to show that this contradicts what's given in the problem?

Comment: @StephenDonovan I got it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, have a nice day! :)